# Can we say "commutative ring = field"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

We know the difference between ring ($R$) and field ($F$) is that $R$ does not guarantee 
multiplication is commutative.

Now, if considering commutative $R$, which means ($R$, $*$) is a group, 
can we say: Commutative ring "$=$" field?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you don't know or understand the definition of a field or a group (e.g. for any nonzero ring $R$, $(R, \cdot)$ is never a group). Perhaps this is the place to start.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164114/is-there-any-difference-between-the-definition-of-a-commutative-ring-and-field

Comment: It is more like: A commutative division ring is the same as a field.

Comment: @ Jeppe...hmm..not exactly. A division ring guarantees multiplicative inverses however not commutitive property. And a commutative ring provides this property. However, it lacks unity. So I think a 'commutative'+'division'+'unity' ring = field.

Comment: Looks to me as if this question was asked on the basis of the words of the definitions, without any consideration of examples. One should always have the *examples* of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ sitting before one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not say that. The flaw in your reasoning is that being commutative does not make $(R,\cdot)$ a group. It does not even make $(R\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ a group. If that was the case, then $R$ would be a field. For $(R\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ to be a group, every nonzero element would have to have an inverse. In the integer numbers $\mathbb Z$, for instance, multiplication is commutative, but $2$ has no multiplicative inverse - after all, $\frac12\notin\mathbb Z$.

Comment: "because" or "but" in the last sentence?

Comment: clearly, that was supposed to be a "but". thx =)

Answer (score 5):

No. $\mathbb{Z}$ is a commutative ring. It is not a field. A fundamental difference is the existence of multiplicative inverses.

Comment: Great example !

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not. For example, the integers under the usual addition and multiplication form a commutative ring that is not a field.

The polynomial with (say) real coefficients are a commutative ring, but not a 
field.

The integers $0,1,2,3,4,5$, under addition and multiplication modulo $6$, are a commutative ring but not a field.

In all the above examples, there are non-zero elements that do not have a multiplicative inverse.